# Building an Nx lib with Rollup does not bundle required dependencies

Tags: javascript, webpack, rollup, nrwl-nx

## Question

I'm using the [default Rollup executor](https://nx.dev/web/package) to build an Nx library that I will later run in a browser-like environment. The resulting bundle cannot contain `import`s or `require`s. Running `nx run ssr-bundle:build` should create a single bundle containing both my application code and dependencies.

How can I bundle all of my code so my `import`ed code is in the same file?

### Example

The source file `index.ts`

```
import { isBoolean } from 'lodash';

async function handler() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(isBoolean);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

export default handler;
```

The output file `index.cjs.js`

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

var lodash = require('lodash'); <--------- this should be the lodash source code

async function handler() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(lodash.isBoolean);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

exports["default"] = handler;
```

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm trying to bundle and publish a package that's referencing local and external deps.

Comment: Not really a direct answer, but you could consider https://github.com/nxext/nx-extensions/tree/main/packages/vite

Answer (score 0):

Rollup:

[multi-entry plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-multi-entry)

rollup.config.js

```
import multi from '@rollup/plugin-multi-entry';

export default {
  input: ['batman.js', 'robin.js', 'joker.js'],
  output: {
    dir: 'output'
  },
  plugins: [multi()]
};
```

Webpack:
Use webpack and specify a single output file.

Webpack.config.js simple example:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  // Specify the entry point of your application
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.tsx"),
  // Specify the output path and name
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../build/"),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
};
```

if you have multiple files that are not imported inside the entry point and want multiple files (or chunks)

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
    search: './src/search.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
  },
};
```

if you want one file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
    search: './src/search.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
  },
};
```

Read more [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/)

Comment: How to do it with `Rollup`? I can also do it with `Vite` but need to do it with `Rollup`

Comment: try https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-multi-entry

Comment: This seems like a sub-standard solution. This might get the job done but not a good solution.